JavaScript Regex Missing a Capture Group with Quantifier
I'm working on some regex patterns and wondering why in my regular expression the middle group is skipped.
Expression:
/^hsl\((\d+)(?:deg)?(?:[\s,]\s*(\d+)%?){2}\)$/

Testing with:
hsl(0,1,2) // PASS = 0, 2 (expecting 0, 1, 2)
hsl(123deg 456% 789%) // PASS = 123, 789 (expecting 123, 456, 789)
hsl(360deg, 50%, 25%) // PASS = 360, 25 (expecting 360, 50, 25)
hsl(532) // FAIL (as intended)

I'm curious why only the last match is captured and the middle is skipped. The expression matches the string correctly otherwise.

The issue with your RegEx lies in how the second capturing group (for middle value) is structured. Specifically, the (?:[\s,]\s*(\d+)%?){2} uses a non-capturing quantifier {2}, and this leads to the behavior you're observing.
Solution:
/^hsl\((\d+)(?:deg)?[\s,]\s*(\d+)%?[\s,]\s*(\d+)%?\)$/


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#using_groups

